# SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "("

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I am trying to call this function

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION get_column_names(param text) 
    RETURNS text AS $get_column_names$
    DECLARE
        return_value text;
        x record;
        y int;
    begin
    return_value := '';
    y := 0;
    for x in SELECT *
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE table_schema = 'public'
        AND table_name   = param 
        ORDER BY ordinal_position
    loop
        if (y = 0)
            then 
            return_value = x.column_name;
        else
            return_value := return_value ||','|| x.column_name;
        end if; 
        Y = Y+1;
    end loop;
    return return_value;
END;
$get_column_names$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Which this function works here

```
select get_column_names('users');
```

Results

```
first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,locale,auth_user_id,identity_id,active,date_created,provisioned,user_id,timezone,last_seen
```

However when I use it in another function I get an error.

Here is the other function I am calling it from.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_users_audit() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $users_audit$
    BEGIN
        --
        -- Create a row in users_audit to reflect the operation performed on users
        --
        IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            INSERT INTO users_audit (user_audit_id, stamp, operation, db_user, get_column_names(TG_TABLE_NAME)) values (uuid_generate_v4(), now(), 'D', user, OLD.*);
            RETURN OLD;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
            INSERT INTO users_audit (user_audit_id, stamp, operation, db_user, get_column_names(TG_TABLE_NAME)) values (uuid_generate_v4(), now(), 'U', user, NEW.*);
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            INSERT INTO users_audit (user_audit_id, stamp, operation, db_user, get_column_names(TG_TABLE_NAME)) values (uuid_generate_v4(), now(), 'I', user, NEW.*);
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
    END;
$users_audit$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The error I am receiving is this (same as title).

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
  Position: 406
```

###### UPDATE

@Ed Brook's answer worked except for had to change how `NEW` was being used. Will remove this update once he has updated his answer but here is what worked.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_audit_table() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $audit_table$
    BEGIN
        --
        -- Create a row in the requesting table's audit to reflect the operation performed on users,
        -- make use of the special variable TG_OP to work out the operation.
        --
        IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') then
            EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || concat(TG_TABLE_NAME, '_audit') || ' (' || get_primary_key_name(concat(TG_TABLE_NAME, '_audit')) || ', stamp, operation, db_user, ' || get_column_names(TG_TABLE_NAME) || ') values (uuid_generate_v4(), now(), ''D'', user, $1.*);'
            USING OLD;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') then
            EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || concat(TG_TABLE_NAME, '_audit') || ' (' || get_primary_key_name(concat(TG_TABLE_NAME, '_audit')) || ', stamp, operation, db_user, ' || get_column_names(TG_TABLE_NAME) || ') values (uuid_generate_v4(), now(), ''U'', user, $1.*);'
            USING NEW;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') then
            EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || concat(TG_TABLE_NAME, '_audit') || ' (' || get_primary_key_name(concat(TG_TABLE_NAME, '_audit')) || ', stamp, operation, db_user, ' || get_column_names(TG_TABLE_NAME) || ') values (uuid_generate_v4(), now(), ''I'', user, $1.*);'
            USING NEW;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
    END;
$audit_table$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Also added some extra bits in there like dynamically getting the audit table name and then `get_primary_key_name` below is that function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_primary_key_name(table_name text) 
    RETURNS text AS $primary_key_name$
    DECLARE 
        return_value text;
    BEGIN 
        SELECT pg_attribute.attname INTO return_value
        FROM pg_index, pg_class, pg_attribute, pg_namespace 
        WHERE pg_class.oid = table_name::regclass
            AND indrelid = pg_class.oid
            AND nspname = 'public'
            AND pg_class.relnamespace = pg_namespace.oid 
            AND pg_attribute.attrelid = pg_class.oid  
            AND pg_attribute.attnum = any(pg_index.indkey)
            AND indisprimary;
        RETURN return_value;
    END
$primary_key_name$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to use `EXECUTE`, as I don't think you can have function calls in the column list?

ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

So, something like this?

```sql
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO users_audit (user_audit_id, stamp, operation, db_user, ' || get_column_names(TG_TABLE_NAME) || ') values (uuid_generate_v4(), now(), ''U'', user, NEW.*)';
```

Comment: would that not apply to `uuid_generate_v4()` and `now()`? I will test this now though.

Comment: The difference is not in getting results from the function, but in how you are using those results. For `uuid_generate_v4()` and `now()` you are using the results as column values. However, you are using the results of your function not as values for a column but as structural elements (column names) of the query. This makes a difference because structural elements must be known when the query is parsed, but getting results from a function only occurs at execution time. You can use `EXECUTE` as it builds another parse/execute cycle after getting the functions results.

Comment: So your solution partially worked I eventually figured it out so that I had to change `NEW.*` to `$1.*` and no semi-colon at the end of that line then on the next line added `USING NEW;` that did the trick, Thank you! if you update your answer I will accept it.